# How can one find the default goal for a maven plugin without reading the source?

Tags: java, maven, maven-plugin

Given a maven plugin, is there any command that one can use to see the default phase/goal bindings for its mojos?  I realize that if I look at the sources or the generated javadocs I can find the annotation.  However that seems too indirect.

I've tried the `:help` goal, but that doesn't give me any additional information either.

Take the [maven-javadoc-plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-javadoc-plugin/) for example.  There are 14 different accessible goals for this plugin.  Yet I do not need to explicitly assign either a phase or a goal for the javadocs to be generated.

Is there any tool I can use to see which goals are assigned by default to which phase (for any plugin - not just the javadoc plugin)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you take a look at the [documentation of the plugins](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-javadoc-plugin/javadoc-mojo.html) you will find something like this:

> Attributes:
>
> ```
> Requires a Maven project to be executed.
> Requires dependency resolution of artifacts in scope: compile.
> The goal is thread-safe and supports parallel builds.
> Since version: 2.0.
> Invokes the execution of the lifecycle phase generate-sources prior to executing itself.
> ```

The last line will give you this information.

Or like this [maven-war-plugin docs:](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/war-mojo.html)

> Attributes:
>
> ```
> Requires a Maven project to be executed.
> Requires dependency resolution of artifacts in scope: runtime.
> The goal is thread-safe and supports parallel builds.
> Binds by default to the lifecycle phase: package.
> ```

Last line shows which is the default life cycle phase.

Apart from the above you can use the binding documentation for the life cycle like this:

https://maven.apache.org/ref/3.0.5/maven-core/default-bindings.html
https://maven.apache.org/ref/3.1.1/maven-core/default-bindings.html
https://maven.apache.org/ref/3.2.5/maven-core/default-bindings.html
https://maven.apache.org/ref/3.3.3/maven-core/default-bindings.html

You can also get those information on command line via:

```
mvn help:describe -DgroupId=org.apache.maven.plugins -DartifactId=maven-jar-plugin  -Ddetail
```

You will get an output like this (plus many more):

```
jar:jar
  Description: Build a JAR from the current project.
  Implementation: org.apache.maven.plugin.jar.JarMojo
  Language: java
  Bound to phase: package

  Available parameters:
  ...
```

And this seemed to me that what you are looking for.